# Leaving a Meeting with permission, but someone was offended

Tags: meetings, probation

During my first month in this new job, I was invited to a meeting.

I came on time, but I realised my colleagues already started many minutes before.  At some point, I was lost, I didn't know what they were talking about.

In the mean time, I had some work that was haunting my mind.

At some point, it felt pointless to stay in the meeting, so I left with permission from my manager.  Apparently someone I did not introduce myself to was offended and does not want to collaborate with me.

Do I deserve to be fired?

Comment: did you just get up and leave or say "Excuse me, its obvious I missed a majority of this meeting and I will be returning back to my work?"

Comment: I asked my boss if I could leave and said "sure" but she seemed not sure why ...

Comment: Is your boss or someone talking about firing you?

Comment: She told me she was not going to extend my probation ... and some gossip says other people incited her to give me a chance or something.

Comment: Well, maybe she thought I forgot something, not just abandon the whole meeting.

Comment: The next day she sounded strange and was very distant.

Comment: You seem to equate "not extend probation" with "fire". In my neck of the woods it means you get off probation and onto regular employment. Or another way. Extending probation is bad.

Comment: If the colleagues had already started many minutes before, how sure are you that you truly were on time?

Answer (score 7):

Is excusing yourself from a meeting a cause for a firing? No.

But you talk about probation period - and technically, not offering permanent employment is not the same as firing - that's the point of probation periods.

I think your behaviour may indicate some other issues that you might want to think about and how they may be affecting your relationship with your boss and employer:

- If there's a new face at the meeting and you are not introduced, you should introduce yourself.
- Don't turn up to a meeting room at the exact time the meeting is supposed to start - be there a couple of minutes early
- If the discussion has already started and you're a bit lost - ask to be caught up - don't ask to be excused
- That person you didn't know sounds like they are probably a major stakeholder in the project - you just demonstrated that you didn't care about their project by asking to leave the meeting - why would they want you working on it?

Answer (score 4):

> Do I deserve to be fired?

So you asked your boss if you could leave, she said yes.  So **no**, you do not deserve to be fired and are probably not at risk of being fired.  I *would* however suggest a follow up with her stating what you have told us.

Try something like:  "*Even though I was on time, it seemed as though I missed a great deal of the context of the meeting and I did not want to waste anyone's time or appear to be disrespectful*."

Then see where the conversation with your manager goes.

*Update based on your OP's comment above*:  If your probationary period was just *barely extended*, I would suggest you begin looking for a new position **ASAP**.

Comment: Well, it seems like the person I didn't introduce myself to was offended and refuses to collaborate with me. Now, my boss won't assign me work related to this and I don't really have a visibility of what I am doing in this new job except for doing some light tasks.

Comment: That is unfortunate.  If at some point in the near future the relationship doesn't improve, you'll need to lean on your manager and work together to make it better.

Comment: The strange thing though, is that when I take a leave of absence (interviewing), she gets upset.

Comment: @Syndicate If the person was offended about not being introduced, then they have some serious issues with professionalism.  It's about generating the best outcome, not about wounded pride.  Your manager should understand this and be able to smooth things over if they are doing their job properly.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is offended and refuses to collaborate with you because you didn’t introduce yourself, then that person is childish and unprofessional. Maybe someone should be fired, but it’s not you.